# Webpack: do not use webpackBoostrap function wrappers

Tags: webpack

I have a question, is it possible to tell webpack not to wrap modules into functions? I need to set this behavior only for specific entries.

I have a set of super legacy code that relies on global object, without explicit access to window or just plain `var`. But as webpack wraps code to function there is no more global scope. I created an entry point which value is array of the files:

```
entry: {
  legacy: {
    filename: 'old/legacy.js',
    import: glob.sync(['legacy/*'], {
      absolute: true,
    }),
  },
}
```

How to tell webpack do not use any wrappers for this bundle. However I need this code to compile through loaders and minification.

I use webpack 5.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I am in the same situation.

Comment: @CashbyCoder I added a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some solutions that could help:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge-and-include-globally
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-concat-files-plugin

However, they do not fit my needs, so I created another package https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-extract-module-to-global

Answer (score 2):

For future reference: Setting [`output.iife`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputiife) to `false` in your webpack config will also stop webpack from wrapping it and expose all variables to the global scope

Comment: This doesn't actually work

Comment: @ChaBukuBakke error on my part: you should set it to false, not true